# Python FPDF rendering issue

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm looking for some assistance with this code below. When I run the "title.py" I get the expected results on a PDF. However, when I import that class into main.py, I get a blank PDF page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

***title.py***:

```
from fpdf import FPDF


class TitlePage(FPDF):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.price_book_title()

    def price_book_title(self):
        self.add_page()
        self.set_font('arial', 'B', 18)
        self.set_text_color(r=11, g=74, b=122)
        title = 'TEST PDF NAME'
        title_w = self.get_string_width(title)
        self.set_xy(x=((self.w - title_w) / 2), y=(self.h / 5))
        self.cell(title_w, txt=title, align='C')


temp = TitlePage()
temp.price_book_title()

temp.output('Title Page Test.pdf')
```

***main.py***

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from title import TitlePage

pdf = FPDF()
title_page = TitlePage()

title_page.price_book_title()

pdf.output('TEST.pdf')
```

Comment: You didn't do anything with the `title_page`.

Comment: @BrainFl ah you're right. I did forget that. Been staring at the screen for too long. How would I go about showing that on a PDF from main.py though. It seems that is where I am stuck. Sorry for the back and forth.

Comment: I'm not a profession at FPDF, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a quick look at the PyFPDF docs [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html#header-footer-page-break-and-image), and I have found a snippet which looks similar to yours - I think you should change your main.py file as follows:

```
from title import TitlePage

title_page = TitlePage()
title_page.price_book_title()
title_page.output('TEST.pdf')
```

Like in the docs snippet, your class extends the *FPDF* class, so you should be able to just call the *output* method on it - the reason why you're getting a blank page is that you're saving the empty document created with `pdf = FPDF()` rather than your class created with `title_page = TitlePage()`.

Comment: Wow. That was solution! I will have to go through that link and read up some more. Thank you!